# Launch Android Map intent with specific direction overlay from directions API result

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm making a navigation application, I have a bunch of routes being returned from Googles Directions API (set alternatives to true), which the user will then choose from. What I'd like to do is launch the Map intent for Google Maps with the selected route passed in.

I'm wondering if this is possible?

I've seen examples of passing in saddr and daddr which will automatically show the best route, but instead I'd like it to display the one selected by a user from one of the direction results which may not the best (most optimum).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the google direction api, I saw that in its response type (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#sample-response), we have for every step, latitude and longitude defined.

Say your output route looks like (this is dummy, not original):

```
                 {
                  ...
                  "routes": [ {
                  "summary": "I-40 W",

                  // There are many legs, but say user choses this below first leg.
                  "legs": [ {
                  "steps": [ 

                  {
                    "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
                    "start_location": {
                    "lat": 41.8507300,
                    "lng": -87.6512600
                    },
                    "end_location": {
                    "lat": 41.8525800,
                    "lng": -87.6514100
                    },
                    "polyline": {
                    "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
                    },
                    "duration": {
                    "value": 19,
                    "text": "1 min"
                    },
                    "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                    "distance": {
                    "value": 207,
                    "text": "0.1 mi"
                    }
                 },

                 {
                    "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
                    "start_location": {
                    "lat": 41.8107300,
                    "lng": -87.6012600
                    },
                    "end_location": {
                    "lat": 41.8725800,
                    "lng": -87.6414100
                    },
                    "polyline": {
                    "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
                    },
                    "duration": {
                    "value": 19,
                    "text": "1 min"
                    },
                    "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                    "distance": {
                    "value": 207,
                    "text": "0.1 mi"
                    }
                 }

                 "start_address": "Oklahoma City, OK, USA",
                 "end_address": "Los Angeles, CA, USA"
                 } ],

                 .... // many other legs ....
                 "legs":[ { ..... } ]
                 .
                 .
                 "copyrights": "Map data ©2010 Google, Sanborn",
                 ...
                 ..
                 .
                 } ] 
                 }
                 ]
                 }
```

Now, above for each step, we have lat and lng entries. We will use those to create our intent request.

Our request will become :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("https://maps.google.ch/maps?saddr=Oklahoma City, OK, USA&daddr=Los Angeles, CA, USA to:41.8525800,-87.6514100 to: 41.8107300,-87.6012600"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Notice that I have used the steps lat and lng along with `to:` prefix in the url. Use can use only upto two `to:` prefixes in this url, because google maps app doesn't acknowledge all the waypoints but only the first and the last, when  passed as intent.

To put it generalized way :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("https://maps.google.ch/maps?saddr=[address1]&daddr=[address2] to:[address3] to: [address4]"));
startActivity(intent);
```

So, this will open google maps app with navigation marked from [address1] to [address2] passing through [address3] and [address4].

Hope this solves problem.

Comment: Yep, I didn't know about the usage of to:, being able to use only 2 of these answers my question perfectly.